# Node.js how to store data in ram

Tags: node.js

When data arrives to node.js server I want to store them in ram.Like this structre:

```
User1Datas:
---ABC1
---ABC2
---ABC3

User2Datas:
---ASD1
---ASD2
---ASD3
...
```

When I call to "get User1Datas" it should return his datas (abc1,abc2,abc3 etc.) 
Also i have to call "delete User1Datas"

What should I use for this? Might be Redis? What do you suggest ?

Comment: What have you tried? There is [flat-file-db](https://www.npmjs.com/package/flat-file-db). Are you needing session management too? [Sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/sessions)

Comment: No,this is a chat system.I will save to ram every message then i will delete them after 10 seconds.

Comment: How about just using a variable? Or look for lru cache packages. Some of them have some really nice features.

Comment: Can you give an example for variable ? I need to store them by username.